# XPATH Query in CQ5

Tags: xpath, aem

I am trying to get all the orders under user. I am using below XPTAH query.

```
/jcr:root/home/users/a/admin/commerce/orders//element(*)[@orderId] this result below records :

/home/users/a/admin/commerce/orders/order-2014-Apr-12
/home/users/a/admin/commerce/orders/order-2015-Apr-15
/home/users/a/admin/commerce/orders/order-2015-Apr-13
```

Now i have requirements that order should be in the sorted order as per booked(that i am looking for) , Other is i will have dynamic parameter which will I pass through the method in which i have the XPTH query executed e.g. 6 or ALL . 6 will display the last 6 months order only (that i am looking for). For all orders i can use the query with sort condition `/jcr:root/home/users/a/admin/commerce/orders//element(*)[@orderId] order by @orderPlaced descending` . I have orderPlaced property of Date type 2014-04-12T17:05:35.085+05:30. So want to put condition result will include last 6 months.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, What I think /jcr:root/home/users/a/admin/commerce/orders//element(*)[@orderId] order by @orderPlaced descending  what should in need to make limit for last 6 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem :

```
type=unstructured
path=/home/users/a/admin/commerce/orders
path.flat=true
orderby=@orderPlaced
orderby.sort=desc
1_relativedaterange.property=orderPlaced
1_relativedaterange.lowerBound=-6M
1_relativedaterange.upperBound=0
```

Answer (score 0):

try the query-debugger located at /libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html
it shows the query in different formats including xpath-syntax. for instance you get the ordering syntax by running this url:

[querydebugger](http://127.0.0.1:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?_charset_=UTF-8&query=type%3Dnt:file%0D%0Anodename%3D*.jar%0D%0Aorderby%3D@jcr:content/jcr:lastModified%0D%0Aorderby.sort%3Ddesc)